# How to Override xml file into Parent Theme

Tags: magento2, layout, overrides, xml

I have installed one plugins 'cedcommerce' and enabled theme (ced_2k18) for it.

My default theme is Porto.

I want to override **ced commerce plugin layout xml file** into my parent theme.

Basically i want to change `/app/design/frontend/Ced/ced_2k18/Ced_CsMarketplace/layout/csmarketplace_account_login.xml`

How can i override this file into `/app/design/frontend/Smartwave/`

I want to add footer of my default theme into the installed extensions.

**I am using magento 2.3**

This is my xml file

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   layout="vendor-empty" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">

<head>
    <meta name="x_ua_compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1,      maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
    <css src="mage/calendar.css"/>

    <css src="Ced_CsMarketplace::bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <css src="Ced_CsMarketplace::bower_components/metisMenu/dist/metisMenu.min.css"/>
    <css src="Ced_CsMarketplace::dist/css/timeline.css"/>
    <css src="Ced_CsMarketplace::dist/css/sb-admin-2.css"/>
    <css src="Ced_CsMarketplace::bower_components/morrisjs/morris.css"/>
    <css src="Ced_CsMarketplace::bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
    <css src="Ced_CsMarketplace::css/ced/csmarketplace/vpanel.css"/>  
</head>
<body>
<referenceContainer name="content">

        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="vendor_page_header" template="Ced_CsMarketplace::customer/form/header.phtml"/>
        <container name="vendor.login.container" label="vendor Login Container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="login-container">
            <block class="Ced\CsMarketplace\Block\Vendor\Form\Login" name="vendor_form_login" template="Ced_CsMarketplace::customer/form/login.phtml" cacheable="false">
                <block class="Ced\CsMarketplace\Block\Vendor\Form\Register" name="customer_form_register" template="Ced_CsMarketplace::customer/form/register.phtml" >
                    <block class="Ced\CsMarketplace\Block\Vendor\Registration\Becomevendor\Form" name="vendor_reg_form" template="Ced_CsMarketplace::vendor/registration/becomevendor/form.phtml" />
                </block>
            </block>
        </container>
    </referenceContainer> 
<referenceContainer name="footer-container">
        <block class="Smartwave\Porto\Block\Template" name="footer_block" template="html/footer.phtml">
            <block class="Magento\Store\Block\Switcher" name="footer.store_switcher" template="switch/stores.phtml"/>
            <block class="Magento\Newsletter\Block\Subscribe" name="footer.newsletter" template="subscribe_footer.phtml"/>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>

</body>
```

Comment: Please share the xml file in your question.

Comment: @sumit Check my updated question

Comment: Please add the page tag as well.

Comment: @sumit added that

Answer (score 0):

You can simply copy this path and paste in your custom theme folder.

`app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Ced_CsMarketplace/layout/csmarketplace_account_login.xml`

**Don't forget to clear cache**

Comment: Thanx. My main motive is, i want to add my default footer on the pages linked witht this extensions. I added my Porto footer block into this xml file, but its not showing up.

Comment: Please let me know how you are adding that block in layout.

Comment: @D Dev added in my question

Comment: Update your layout from `vendor-empty`to `1column`

Comment: changed but did not work.